# Ruby/Mechanize workaround for Let’s Encrypt Root Certificate Expiration and OpenSSL 1.0.2

Tags: ruby, openssl, ssl-certificate, mechanize, lets-encrypt

With the [expiration](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/) of Let's Encrypt's root certificate DST Root CA X3, my ruby scripts using OpenSSL to connect to servers that use this certificate are returning the error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

This can be overridden with:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

however this is obviously horribly insecure.

The OpenSSL [blog](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2021/09/13/LetsEncryptRootCertExpire/) suggests modifying the trust store, which I would rather not do, or a workaround via code, as follows:

> call X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags() function with the X509_V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST flag

My attempt to set this flag:

```
OpenSSL::X509::X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags(OpenSSL::X509::X509_V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST)
```

returns

```
uninitialized constant OpenSSL::X509::X509_V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST (NameError)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, the constant is `OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST`. The flag can be set on the `OpenSSL::X509::Store` instance of the client as [`OpenSSL::X509::Store#flags=`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Store.html#method-i-flags-3D)

You would have to figure out however how you can access this `OpenSSL::X509::Store` instance of your library...

In any case, the recommended approach would in fact be to either update to a more recent Ruby (and OpenSSL) as OpenSSL 1.0.2 does not receive ANY public security updates any more. OpenSSL 1.1 is supported since Ruby 2.5.

Alternatively, you can also adjust your system's trust store and remove the expired root certificate. This should have no negative consequences since it will be invalid for verification anyway.

Comment: Available flags can be found [Here](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/blob/master/ext/openssl/ossl_x509.c#L147)

Comment: Trying to use OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST produces the same error message: uninitialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST (NameError). I still do not know how to set this flag as suggested by the Open SSL blog.